# Convert serbian cyrilic to latin - charon issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am using simple dictionary to replace Cyrillic letters with latin ones and most of the time its working just fine but I am having issues with letters with charon (čšđćž...).

Few examples:

From "MEЂУНАРОДНО" I am getting this "ME\u0110UNARODNO" instead of "MEĐUNARODNO"

From "ЖИВОТ" I am getting "\u017DIVOT" instead of "ŽIVOT"

From "ЧАС" I am getting "\u010CAS"  instead of "ČAS"

Anyone know why and of course what is possible solution to this? Thanks

This is the code and a dictionary I am using.

```
public string ConvertCyrillicToLatin(string text)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            words.Add("А", "A");
            words.Add("Б", "B");
            words.Add("В", "V");
            words.Add("Г", "G");
            words.Add("Д", "D");
            words.Add("Ђ", "Đ");
            words.Add("Е", "E");
            words.Add("Ж", "Ž");
            words.Add("З", "Z");
            words.Add("И", "I");
            words.Add("Ј", "J");
            words.Add("К", "K");
            words.Add("Л", "L");
            words.Add("Љ", "Lj");
            words.Add("М", "M");
            words.Add("Н", "N");
            words.Add("Њ", "Nj");
            words.Add("О", "O");
            words.Add("П", "P");
            words.Add("Р", "R");
            words.Add("С", "S");
            words.Add("Т", "T");
            words.Add("Ћ", "Ć");
            words.Add("У", "U");
            words.Add("Ф", "F");
            words.Add("Х", "H");
            words.Add("Ц", "C");
            words.Add("Ч", "Č");
            words.Add("Џ", "Dž");
            words.Add("Ш", "Š");
            words.Add("а", "a");
            words.Add("б", "b");
            words.Add("в", "v");
            words.Add("г", "g");
            words.Add("д", "d");
            words.Add("ђ", "đ");
            words.Add("е", "e");
            words.Add("ж", "ž");
            words.Add("з", "z");
            words.Add("и", "i");
            words.Add("ј", "j");
            words.Add("к", "k");
            words.Add("л", "l");
            words.Add("љ", "lj");
            words.Add("м", "m");
            words.Add("н", "n");
            words.Add("њ", "nj");
            words.Add("о", "o");
            words.Add("п", "p");
            words.Add("р", "r");
            words.Add("с", "s");
            words.Add("т", "t");
            words.Add("ћ", "ć");
            words.Add("у", "u");
            words.Add("ф", "f");
            words.Add("х", "h");
            words.Add("ц", "c");
            words.Add("ч", "č");
            words.Add("џ", "dž");
            words.Add("ш", "š");

            var source = text;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in words)
            {
                source = source.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }

            return source;
        }
```

Comment: How are you displaying the output? It looks fine for me, but I suspect your UI isn't using Unicode.

Comment: I am placing converted text inside a property model and then displaying it as json. I need a json because of front end part (angular). Error is on backend side, angular part still doesnt exist.

Comment: Your comment have gave me an idea to try something. Till now I was using google chrome (UI) to call the API and I was getting the errors mentioned above, so I tried calling the API with Postman and its displaying without any issues :) thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like David mentioned in the comment, check the UI :)  so I did.

Because front end still doesnt exist, I was using Chrome to call the API and check the results but after I switched to Postman, the wrong conversion was gone, so the answer is check your UI.